# -webkit-appearance forcing transitions?

Tags: css, css-transitions, webkit-appearance

Given a basic HTML template and CSS style, I'm seeing two different elements react completely different.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  document.body.id = 'animate';
}, 100);
```

```css
#animate input[type="checkbox"]{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: 2s all;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}
#animate div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background:blue;
  transition: 2s all;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"/>
<div></div>
```

If you open this in a browser, you see that, on load, the div already has its 100px height/width, yet the checkbox grows from 0px to 100px height/width over 2s.

[image]

**Why does the `input` behave differently than the `div`? Is it because the input has default `-webkit-appearance` giving it something to transition between?**

Comment: Definitely seems like it. Though I can't seem to find any `width` or `height` declarations for `input[type=checkbox]` in [Webkit's user agent stylesheet, except for in iOS](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css#L787). I could be wrong.

Comment: @darrylyeo I couldn't find any either and when toggling them off in element inspector they dropped back to 0. That made me even more confused.

Comment: Interestingly, when hovering over the `width` and `height` entries in the Computed tab of Chrome's Developer Tools, there is no arrow that takes you to the source!

Comment: I believe it is because a div doesn't have a height/width already set as a default style (its width is 100% of whatever its container is by default and its height is determined by its content), whereas a checkbox has a default size to use as a starting point. Without a starting point, transitioned elements will just start out at their specified size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `div`'s default width/height is auto and as such it won't animate.

The `input` has a default width/height and as such will animate.

*As a side note, the transition does work on the `div`, though only animate its color, as it is possible to animate a color from `transparent` to `blue`*

*You should also consider to **not** use `all` with `transition`, as it can give unpredictalbe result because of this fact that browsers does set some values on elements to a default value, where some can be animated, some can't.*

*So, in your case, if your intention is to animate width/height, set it up like this: `transiton: width 2s ease, height 2s ease;`*

Comment: Where are these default height/width though? If you look in the element inspector you can't see any, is it stored in the  -webkit-appearance: checkbox;?

Comment: @DasBeasto Replaced elements can have an intrinsic size. For example an `<img>` element has the size of the image, and that size does not come from the CSS cascade.

Comment: @DasBeasto No, elements default values is set in the user agent stylesheet. If you inspect an element with Chrome, some of those values is showed with a gray background, some is not

Comment: @Oriol Good point with the image, I always figured user agent styles were always shown but I realize some (a lot?) are not, thanks!

Comment: @DasBeasto What happens is that e.g. the initial `width: auto` can resolve into different lengths, depending on various things. CSS inspectors usually show all the declared values or the cascaded value, so you may not notice the resulting used or actual value.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple. The `input`'s style has a *pre-loaded values* in the DOM, that's why just right after appearing in the document, smoothly changes his shape.

Quite contrary with the `div` element. The `div` hasn't any *pre-loaded, default values* in the DOM before setting them by the user. That's why it appears in the document with already set size.

**Important note**
If you want the transition to work, it has to have a set, starting, default value and ending value. The animation will occur between these two values. The `input` has already set the default value of the size, that's why the animation will occur.

You may ask, so why the `background` transition is working? It works, since the default value of `background` is *transparent*.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.xx').addClass('x');
}, 500);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
input[type="checkbox"] {} div {} .x {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: all 2s ease;
  background: blue;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>

  <input type='checkbox'>
  <div class='xx'></div>
  <input class='xx' type="checkbox">

</div>
```

Comment: @DasBeasto You have disappointed me, even if I've provided the most valuable answer, you marked another one as the best one. I'm really disappointed.

Comment: That's not it works, @K.Daniek. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: @K.Daniek LGSon sufficiently answered my question. Your answer provides that same information that LGSon did, in my opinion. Except his was first so I accepted it.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer without being to technical. CSS transition's will do it's job when there is a previous state to start animate from.

A default `div` doesn't have any styling by default.
An `input` element is always pre-styled in the browser itself.

Here is a fiddle that can be used to re-create the behaviour that the OP mentioned. It simulate external loading with a simply JS delay. https://jsfiddle.net/xvt359ju/1/

Nevermind, 2 other answers was faster than me.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers have their own basic CSS styling of elements, the checkbox too have it. When you inspect the element you can see width and height to the checkbox applied by the browser, that will be overridden when your external stylesheets loads. And animating it as you have given transition to it.